# Python code to parse large JSON data and host online but refresh periodically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json, couchdb

I'm going to explain what I'm trying to do before I ask my specific question.

I'm taking a large set of JSON data from a CouchDB of keys mapping to values which contain the URL of other JSON objects. I wrote a python file that parses through the original JSON object, opens the URL to the other ones contained in there, and saves all the data in a URL. However, it takes about 11 seconds to open this URL every time.

Is there a possible way that I can have a python file to parse this JSON object every 15 minutes or so and host it online so that I can access it without it taking forever to load but still be able to update every 15 minutes?

I am using the data from this JSON object to make a javascript/jquery web page and the web page takes forever to load as well.

Thank you!

Comment: Cache the results of the HTTP requests. If you use a [timestamp as part of the cache key](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578817-lru_timestamp-cache-entry-aging-for-functoolslru_c/), you can easily build yourself a cache that expires its entries after 15min.

Comment: Can you give an example for such an URL? If the web server that serves it correctly sets the `Last-Modified` headers and supports conditional `GET` (`If-Modified-Since`) requests, you can avoid fetching the resource unless is has changed.

Answer (score 0):

If couchdb site is under your control it would probably be better to set up some kind of caching. Either cache results in the client (maybe use [shove](https://bitbucket.org/lcrees/shove/)), or use some kind of caching proxy server to cache requests (maybe [varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/)). Your python solution would probably amount to reimplementing simpler version of such tool.